# Typing Url loads php and enters empty values in data base. How to avoid?

Tags: php

If i enter the url of my php code it is running directly and submitting the empty values into the data base. I want that php file to run only when submit button is pressed not when entering url directly. please help me

Comment: You need some server side validation. Or you could you $_POST and not $_GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the beginning of your file make sure to verify that your $_GET or $_POST array (depending on what method are you using for submiting your form) contains some minimal amount of data.

Assuming that you have two input element (name and surname) on your form such as:

```
<form action='myscript.php' method='post'>
     <input type='text' name='firstname' value='' /><br/>
     <input type='text' name='surname' value='' /><br/>
     <input type='submit' name='do' value=' submit this form ' />
</form>
```

then on the beginning of your file (in my example it's called `myscript.php`) you will have something like this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['firstname']) || strlen($_POST['firstname'])<4)
    die("You did not fill in the form properly - first name must be longer than 4 
if (!isset($_POST['surname']) || strlen($_POST['surname'])<3)
    die("You did not fill in the form properly - surname must be longer than 3 characters!");
//and here continues your code, where you save the surname and first name to the database
```

Comment: @praveenrsmart You click the arrow up (to the left of answer) at each answer you liked or that helped you. Choosing your favorite (and accepting it) you already did. :) Thank you for that :) btw don't worry about being new, we all are (or were at some point) :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if one of the variables is set.

```
if (isset($_POST['oneOfMyVariables'])) {
  //run some code only if something or many things are send. Whatever.
}
```

That will stop it from running unless the variable(s) have been set.

Comment: how to do that. i am new here

Comment: I'm also new to StackOverFlow. What can't you do? (I just saw this now.)